# How do I set editable property of p-column dynamically in ngprime p-datatable

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using p-datatable from ngprime.

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="config" [(selection)]="selectedEnviornment" [editable]="true">
  <p-column field="userName" header="User Name" [editable]="false"></p-column>
    <p-column field="password" header="Email" [editable]="false"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

In my component.ts

```
for (var index = 0; index < this.config.length; index++) {
this.config[index].editable=true;
      }},
```

Here I have set editable property of my `config` which is set of rows in p-datatable.

How do I access "`editable`" property of row from component and set it to `editable` property of `p-column`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: A cell is either editable or read-only for entire set of data. It can not be customized for each element in set. Do you have any specific requirement here? You should try ng-template for editor.

Comment: ng-template would make it very complicated. I was hoping to have a property provided by ngprime to edit one row on rowselect event

Comment: Check out if helps.. http://plnkr.co/edit/sFrICY?p=preview .

Comment: Maybe try add function which will be called after click on row, and send to this function clicked row object and then in this function check if this row is editable

Comment: @porgo. Editable property doesnt work with rowselect event, thats first thing. another is editable property is not available per row.

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding for setting the parameter

`[hidden]="yourHiddenParam"`

and then in the component declaration:
`yourHiddenParam: string = 'false';`

Then change the variable.